# How do I set a custom resolution?

Tags: what-remains-of-edith-finch

I am not able to change my resolution in-game. My native resolution is 1366x768, but the game only allows me to choose between 1440x810 and 1280x720, and it also only allows me to choose windowed mode, whereas in fullscreen or full-windowed it is locked at 1440x810.

I tried changing it in the game's config file but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In the game launch options, put `-w 1366 -h 768 -fullscreen` (I think it's like that). Other than that it might just be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to the What remains of Edith Finch user settings folder (default: *%LOCALAPPDATA%\FinchGame\Saved\Config\WindowsNoEditor\*).
- Open *GameUserSettings.ini*.
- Set your custom resolution by changing the values for `ResolutionSizeX` (horizontal) and `ResolutionSizeY` (vertical).
- Here you can also set `FullscreenMode=` to `0` or `1`, depending on what is used, as this can cause problems setting the resolution.

Set this file to read-only afterwards, by right-clicking the file, selecting Properties, and selecting the read-only flag. This will ensure the game won't merrily reset to its default values.